# Is it reasonable to include both independent variables and their interaction terms in a linear predictive model?

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

Suppose i have outcome variable O (effective/not effective), drug dosage A and variables B&C, and i want to train a linear model to predict O. B&C can only influence O by modifying metabolism of A, thus i believe i should include B&C as  interaction terms in the linear model. I found two choices:

1)O~A+A * B+A * C

2)O~A * B+A * C

I'm not sure which is the reasonable formula for the predictive model. Wish to learn from you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your notation supposed to represent R code?

Comment: If so, A*B contains both main effects and the interaction together i.e. it is the same as A + B + A:B

Comment: Indeed, ~ and * are R commands. Does that means formula 2 is sufficient?

Comment: No, because you have redundant terms. The main effect of A appears thrice in model 1 and twice in model 2. R may deal with that intelligently, but it is best to specify exactly what model you are trying to fit. The problem here is that we do not know exactly what your intended models are because they are not specified properly. It would help if you edited them to clarify this.

Comment: Also, it looks like your outcome is binary so you should be using logistic regression, not linear